# How to redirect user to another location from particular folder if there is no extension(like .png,.jpg) exist at the end of url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect all url of particular folder to another location if there is no extension exist at the end of url.

I have "Test" folder in the server.

my url are like

```
www.example.com/Test/abc
www.example.com/Test/abc1
www.example.com/Test/abc2
```

So i want that when user click on these url then it will be redirect to the index page(www.example.com/index.php)

But if url have extension at the end then it should not be redirect.

like `www.example.com/Test/logo.jpg, www.example.com/Test/p1.mp3`

I have tried to do it using .htaccess file. and i am able to redirect to index page but my problem is that when user click on any image url or mp3 url then it will also redirect user to index page.

here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
Redirect /Test http://example.com/index.php?id=
</IfModule>
```

It redirect me to the following url

```
http://example.com/index.php?id=abc (if i clicked on http://example.com/Test/abc)
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well in `.htaccess` you could do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)\.jpg$ /index.php?id=$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)\.mp3$ /index.php?id=$1.mp3 [L]
```

If you want a `301` redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|mp3)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am using Redirect instead of RewriteRule, Can you please give some idea for Redirect /Test http://example.com/index.php?id=

Comment: You won't be able to do that kind of redirect without `RewriteRule`. If you want you can do `Redirect 301 /Test/logo.jpg http://example.com/index.php?id=logo.jpg` and for each file you would have to make a seperate rule with that kind of redirect. In your `.htaccess` you have `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` so why nor use `RewriteRule`?

Comment: @arunkamboj tested the 301 redirect with `RewriteRule` and have a 100% success rate.

Comment: I have used the following .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond $1 !^(\.jpg|\.mp3|\.xml)
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

But still its not working, Its also redirect the jpg and xml file path into index page

Comment: @arunkamboj I don't understand why did you accept an answer that does not work and redirectes to index.php but under my answer you are saying that you don't want a redirect to index.php... You havn't even tested 301 redirect as I can tell.

Comment: Actually i am new in htaccess, your solution was not working for me and i don't have enough knowledge to customize your solution according to my requirements and when i  used the M.Bains solution then its worked to my requirements.

Comment: I just matched your previous comment, You haven't set the [NC] flag there. I think that's why it was not working for me.

Comment: My point is in your question you wanted `http://example.com/Test/abc` to go to `http://example.com/index.php?id=abc` and that is what the 301 solution I gave does. The answer you selected just goes to index.php... it's not even the thing you wanted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $extension=end(explode(".",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    $arr=["png","jpg"];
    if(in_array(strtolower($extension), $arr)==""){
        header("location:https://www.google.com");
    } ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't use `.htaccess` and the location url is wrong.

Comment: create a file in that folder with index.php name and paste my code and replace the location to your desired location. I hope this will work

Comment: Still won't work. You would have to get the file and attach it to the proper location. Changing the location by itself won't do a thing. The only thing you are doing here is checking the file extension. You're not even checking if the url is the one we want to check in.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this? I have not tested it but it should work for you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule \.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|xml|html|mp3|ttf|eot)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```